# Creating two seperate columns through the same column identifier

Tags: sql

I want to display two different columns that use the same table identifier, but I end up with the same column twice.

There is one table that includes the following info:

```
Entity // Amount     // SupplierID // ManagerID  
-----------
A      // 54816.65   //  154       //    15  
A      // 18511.55   //  163       //    15  
B      // 51616.69   //  415       //    8  
C      // 32178.32   //  846       //    6
```

There is another table that includes all the companies in our database structured like that

```
CompanyID   //   CompanyName
-----------
1           //     Company 1  
2           //     Company 2  
3           //     Company 3  
[...]  
6486        //     Company 6486  
6487        //     Company 6487
```

On my final display I want to have the company names instead of the company ID. So far, I had only needed to display either the company or the manager therefore I would do a join of the two tables on the ID, as per below

```
SELECT Companyname
FROM table 2
INNER JOIN table 1
ON SupplierID=CompanyID
```

Given the fact that there is only one column [Company Name], I am not sure how I can use the information from this column, but display it on two seperate columns based on the ID that is being tied to. (e.g. SupplierID, ManagerID)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You must join `table1` twice with `table2`:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
  s.Companyname SupplierCompanyName,
  m.Companyname ManagerCompanyName
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 s ON t1.SupplierID = t2.CompanyID
INNER JOIN table2 m ON t1.ManagerID = t2.CompanyID
```